# How to check if a string contains only comma, in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-lookarounds

I have a string in VB.net that can contain only commas, or a combination of letters, numbers and special characters.

For example, my string can be `A,-,$,2`  or  `,,,`

How can I determine using a regex if my string only has commas?

Comment: Did you look into how to use some of the regex functions in VB and learn at least a little how regex work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to match a string of only commas?

I suggest you check out the [Regex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) and look at using `System.Text.RegularExpressions` along with the [Regex.Match Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) and [Regex.Matches Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx)

```
Dim input As String = ",,,,,"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, "^,*$")
If (m.Success) Then
    Console.WriteLine("string has comma's")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use RegEx, you can use the .Distinct() extension method on the string, since a string is nothing more than a collection of characters.

```
Dim distinctValues = testString.Distinct()

If distinctValues = "," Then
    'Do Something
Else
    'Do Something Else
End If
```

Comment: Thanks all. I chose to go by regex method. Thanks kippermand for your alternate solution to regex.